# Check if a player is in a lobby

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality, photon

I am trying to fix a bug for my Unity Photon VR game. The issue that is I do not know how to check if you are connected to a lobby.

I tried to make a script, where if you are connected to a server, it would disable the offline rig. The problem is that I don't know how to check whether a player is connected to a lobby.

This is my code:

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    if (//player is conneced to lobby) = true)
    {
        OfflineRig.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        OfflineRig.SetActive(true);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us some code first of all? To see where you are stuck etc.?

Comment: [`OfflineRig.SetActive(!PhotonNetwork.InLobby);`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#ab9242401016d7728479c4298e98c0090) ...?